# Length of cell element in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have this cell array:

```
ca = {'a', {'b', 'c'}}
```

then

```
>> c = ca(2)
c = {1x2 cell}
>> length(c)
ans = 1
```

why is that?  Isn't the length of 1x2 cell array 2? why is it 1?

Answer (score 0):

That's the length of the second element of your first cell array `ca`. Like with regular arrays, a single element of a cell array has length 1. However, each cell array element can contain objects/data of arbitrary length. To get the length of the *contents* of the second element you need to use curly braces:

```
c = ca{2}
length(c)
```

Also note how `ca(2)` and `ca{2}` are displayed differently in the Command Window. Read more about accessing cell arrays [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html).